# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I have a very simple [HTML page](http://cfl.bitballoon.com/) and I try to execute a simple CSS selector, using cheerio.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($(`body > div > div.-layout-h > div.task-tests--label`).text());
```

Result:
`Input:Output: Expected Output:Console Output:`

My goal is to get the first element and print out its inner text. I have also tried iterating over the selected elements with `each()`:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
$(`body > div > div.-layout-h > div.task-tests--label`).each((i, e) => {
    console.log(`${i} = ${e.text()}`);
});
```

Result:

```
0 = [object Object]
1 = [object Object]
2 = [object Object]
3 = [object Object]
```

How do I print the inner text of every selected item?

Comment: jQuery isn't included on the page in question, so `$()` isn't jQuery, it is the console's built-in convenience `$()` function, which returns an object that does *not* have a `.text()` method. Regarding why you might get all four elements printed, that's because the selector matches them all.

Comment: Add <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to your head tag

Comment: @YasharAliabasi - surely with at least // at the start of the URL

Comment: @nnnnnn got it, so how would one get the object's text in Chrome's dev tools?

Comment: @Amadan - if `$` is the console's built-in function it will only return one record. (It's basically a shortcut to `querySelector()`, isn't it, with `$$()` being a shortcut to `querySelectorAll()`?) But yes, `$(selector).textContent` should work.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Ah derp. :) Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX I pasted from [`cdjns`](https://cdnjs.com/) but unfortunately `stack` removed it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show clicked element text you should use `this` for understanding see this example

```js
$('#change').click(function () {
$(this).text('this text changed');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">hello world</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

Add the below tag to you head section.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use

```
console.log($(`.task-tests--label`).text());
```

to make your life easier. The above code will select all the tags with class "***task-tests--label***" and console out their respective text.